# Merge a feature branch in several branches

Tags: git

I feel like there should be an easy way to push a feature in several branches without doing the work twice, but I can't find it.

Let's say I have two main branches: current_version and previous_version. I want to add a very simple feature, like just add a line in a configuration file.

I create a feature_branch to deliver the modification. Ideally I would like to create two PR to merge this branch with current_version and previous_version.

But:

- If my feature_branch has been created from previous_version, I have other commits in the PR for current_version
- And the other way around if it was branched from current_version
- If it was created from the merge-base of previous_version and current_version I get conflicts for both

So:

1. Is there a way to do that with a single feature_branch ?
2. If not simultaneously maybe reusing the feature_branch after the first PR is merged ? Using a rebase ? In which order ?
3. If I need to use two feature branches, can I branch the second one from the first one (again the goal is to only do the modifications once) and use a rebase ?
4. Can this second approach be used for simultaneous PR ? (I think there would be no difference with question 2 if it was done one after the other).
5. Maybe cherry-picking commits ? But I'd like to get all the changes in feature_branch at once.

I've experimented a bit with these options, using rebase, rebase --onto, etc. But I could not identify a working flow.

It feels like it should be a common situation with a common solution though ? Or I may be misusing git ?

Edit: Another possibility with rebase:
From what I understand, assuming my feature_branch branched from previous_version,
git rebase --onto current_version previous_version feature_branch
would basically do what I want: move all commits that feature_branch added on top of previous_version to the top of current_version.

However this moves the whole branch. I basically would like a copy of it instead, because I still need to merge it in 2 pull request.
And if I merge first, the rebase --onto doesn't work anymore (I assume because at this point there is no more difference between previous_version and feature_branch).

6. Could I maybe create a branch that is a copy of this rebase, leaving the original in place ?
7. Or maybe if I create a feature_branch_current on top of feature_branch and rebase it ?
8. Or instead of top could I have my feature_branch_current be an exact copy of feature_branch and then rebase it while leaving the first one in place ?

Comment: The way you describe it, it looks like previous_version and current_version have diverged. In this case, you should branch off feature_branch from a commit that is common to both. Then you can merge it into the two version branches without introducing unwanted commits.

Comment: @j6t previous_version contains some fixes, current_version contains new features. So yes they have diverged. Like I mentioned if I start feature_branch from the merge-base of both versions, I have (different) conflicts on both.

Comment: OK, then it's a matter of "choose your poison" ;)

Comment: Dealing with conflicts is better than having to diverge things even more by using rebase or cherry-pick.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I tried, but haven't really tested yet on real cases:

Create feature_branch_current from current then:

```
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list $(git merge-base previous_version feature_branch)..feature_branch)
```

Would love feedback on that and/or issues I could have missed with it